# NameError: name 'No' is not defined

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, cal

When i press any number in my calculator showing error

```
from tkinter import *

def btnclick (numbers):
    global operator
    operator=operator + str(No)
    text_Input.set(operator)

def btnClearDisplay():
    global operator
    operator=""
    text_Input.set("")

def btnEqualsInput():
     global operator
     sumup=str(eval(operator))
     text_Input.set(sumup)
     operator=""
```

**Error:**

```
line 5, in btnclick
    operator=operator + str(No)
NameError: name 'No' is not defined
```

Comment: Uh... yeah. `No` isn't defined. What did you expect `No` to refer to when you wrote `operator=operator + str(No)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct this `numbers`

```
operator=operator + str(numbers)
```

After run your programs

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `operator = operator + str(numbers)` because your function parameter is `numbers`.